# Position Fixed to the Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, tumblr

I have a Tumblr account and I'm working on editing the html of it. My question is this: how do I make my side bar be in a certain position but then when I scroll down on the page, it stays where it is relative to my browser? For an example of what I'm talking about, click ask a question and look at "similar questions" then scroll. I would prefer for it to be in CSS. I have already tried everything I can think of.

http://snipt.org/AGff7

That is the code that I'm starting with, plus my custom CSS which is at the end of `<style>`

I have already tried `position:fixed`.

I want it to start in the middle of the browser window then when i scroll down, it hits the top of the window and stays fixed relative to the window.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely going to need to make use of JS for this as CSS won't be able to detect scrolling. Here's a basic example:

```
<div id="scroller" class="floating"></div>
```

This is our original element, where it's already partially down the page and floating in the middle. style like

```
.floating{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

We then need to use Javascript in order to measure when the user has scrolled down (I've done this using jQuery)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50){
        $('#scroller').removeClass('floating');
        $('#scroller').addClass('fixed');
    }else{
        $('#scroller').addClass('floating');
        $('#scroller').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

where you have an alternative css declaration for fixed like

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a quick code that has everything here its supposed to be relative to the various tags that are involved? Because yesterday was my first day even attempting something with JavaScript. Am I going to need to add 'code'<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>'code' to the head of my document? And if you do make a mini code, could you call the object in question something like "cube" so I know what your talking about and make all numbers that are changeable something like 999? You don't have to make code for the actual object itself.

Comment: Okay, you need to add <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"> to the footer of your body. After this you can put the javascript I wrote into a separate <script> tag.

Comment: I currntly have the script src in the head btu how do i define what the actual script itself pertains to?